# Toolchain build using yocto

Tags: yocto, toolchain

I have cloned yocto using the following command.

```
git clone -b warrior git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
```

I want to build ARM toolchain, can you guide which meta data I have to modify for this.

Comment: Which machine you want to support?

Comment: I want ARM toolchain for IMX6 machine. Is it possible to build ARM toolchain using Yocto which is not specific to any machine.

Comment: I'm not sure, I would create a imx6 sdk through `bitbake core-image-minimal -c populate_sdk` with [fslc environment](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform)

Comment: Tried with the [fsl community bsp](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform), can you guide to know how they are selecting which version of toolchian to build and use. I could see gcc recipes are available under `recipes-devtools` folder.

Comment: Could you try `bitbake -e | grep ^PREFERRED_VERSION` ?

Comment: Could able to see the [output](https://pastebin.com/QR2YUd7f) of the command, these variables are set in the `tcmode-default.inc` file.

Answer (score 0):

For an i.MX6 toolchain and image you should do something like this (adapted from the instructions at https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform ):

```
sudo apt install repo         # on Ubuntu/Debian
mkdir fsl-community-bsp
cd fsl-community-bsp
repo init -u https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform -b thud
repo sync
source ./setup-environment    # to see the list of MACHINE and DISTRO values
MACHINE=imx6blahblah DISTRO=fslc-x11 source ./setup-environment build
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

You should substitute `imx6blahblah`, `fslc-x11`, and `build` with the correct machine and distro, and whatever you want your build directory to be called.

Instead of thud (Yocto 2.6), you could build for zeus (Yocto 3.0) or warrior, but the default branch of the NXP BSP as of today is thud.

While you could build a generic toolchain by making an image for qemu-arm, you could not build the Linux kernel or u-boot that would run on an i.MX6 and many recipes involving audio, video, and crypto would run very poorly or require extensive modification to run on a "generic arm" target.